# WP7 NetworkInterface.GetInternetInterfaceType()

Tags: networking, windows-phone-7

I would like to determine programatically if the phone is connected to Wifi or not.  I have found a number of references to the NetworkInterface.GetInternetInterfaceType() method (supposedly in Microsoft.Devices.dll).  I'm having trouble locating this method - using Windows Phone 7.0.  Can someone point me in the right direction.  I have located the GetIsNetworkAvailable method - however I want to actually determine the type of network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType.

e.g. if (Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)

Part of my original problem was that I was originally referencing the System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace instead of the Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation namespace.

Comment: Remember that even if a connection to a wifi network is available it doesn't mean that any network requests using that connection will work. You still need to handle requests failing.